# sort a string in recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

I have a certain string and I want to sort it in recursion.

My code is error free but the algorithm is not working and I need help

The index will be zero when calling the function.

The main idea is the compare between indexes in the string and creating a new string each time with the new sequence of the letters compared.

each call I send the new string which was created in each run

```
private static String sort(String s1, int index)
{

    String s2="";
    if (index == s1.length()-2)
        return s1;
    else
    {
        if (s1.charAt(index) > s1.charAt(index+1))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
            {
                if (index == i)
                {
                    s2 += s1.charAt(index+1);
                    s2 += s1.charAt(index);
                    i += 2;
                }
                s2 += s1.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
            {
                if (index == i)
                {
                    s2 += s1.charAt(index);
                    s2 += s1.charAt(index+1);
                    i += 2;
                }
                s2 += s1.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return (sort(s2,++index));  
    }
}
```

input : `acbacds`
output: `abaccds`

the output should be : `aabccds`

Comment: What errors are being displayed in the console? Also, this forum is to help **you** fix errors, not do it for you.

Comment: I don't have errors any more, I'll edit the code I wrote in the question.
I have issues with the output

Comment: "My code is error free but the algorithm is not working" that confusion of thought will not serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

Each call compares a pair of adjacent characters; if they're out of order, you switch them.

Your recursion simply replaces an outer loop running through the length of the array.

The end of this process guarantees that the largest value will now be at the end of the array.  To this extent, it works correctly.

If you expect an array of N elements to get fully sorted, you must repeat this process up to N-1 times.  The only reason your given example is so close is that the array you gave it is already very close to sorted.

Try again with something in reverse order, and you'll see the effect.  For instance, use "hgfedcba".  One pass will get you "gfedcbah", moving the 'h' from the front to the end.

If you want a working bubble sort, try searching here on SO or on the web overall.

Finally, you might look into the Java substring functions; building **s2** a character at a time is hard on the eyes; it's also slow, especially in the case where you don't switch characters.